# brew install python failed after install pyenv

Tags: python, homebrew, python-sphinx

Ever since I installed pyenv on my mac to manage python versions. Something goes wrong with my brew. Whenever I install something depends on python brew install python from source and fail with exception. I try to install python directly but the result is same

output:

```
➜  ~ brew install python
Warning: Building python from source:
  The bottle needs the Apple Command Line Tools to be installed.
  You can install them, if desired, with:
    xcode-select --install

==> Downloading https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/fengweizhou/Library/Caches/Homebrew/python-3.6.5.tar.xz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5 --enable-ipv6 --datarootd
==> make
==> make install PYTHONAPPSDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5
==> make frameworkinstallextras PYTHONAPPSDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/shar
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/72/c2/c09362ab29338413ab6
Already downloaded: /Users/fengweizhou/Library/Caches/Homebrew/python--setuptools-39.0.1.zip
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/e8/2340d46ecadb1692a1e
Already downloaded: /Users/fengweizhou/Library/Caches/Homebrew/python--pip-10.0.1.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5d/c1/45947333669b31bc6b4
Already downloaded: /Users/fengweizhou/Library/Caches/Homebrew/python--wheel-0.31.0.tar.gz
==> make html
Last 15 lines from /Users/fengweizhou/Library/Logs/Homebrew/python/05.make:
html

mkdir -p build
Using existing Misc/NEWS file
PATH=./venv/bin:$PATH sphinx-build -b html -d build/doctrees -D latex_elements.papersize=  . build/html
Running Sphinx v1.7.4

Exception occurred:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 355, in <module>
    class _OutputRedirectingPdb(pdb.Pdb):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Pdb'
The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-0dDG9t.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time.
A bug report can be filed in the tracker at <https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues>. Thanks!
make: *** [build] Error 2

READ THIS: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
Switch --with-python option for GDB formula to Python 3. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/24524
Change cookiecutter to depend on Python 3 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/27028
neovim: Add caveats for Python/Ruby support https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/26869
libpeas: add support for running python plugins https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/22430

Error: Your Xcode (9.2) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 9.3 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

I don't know much about the Sphinx thing. So why does it throw that exception here?

After uninstall pyenv the result is still the same.

The full traceback in /tmp/sphinx-err-0dDG9t.log is

```
# Sphinx version: 1.7.4
# Python version: 2.7.10 (CPython)
# Docutils version: 0.14 
# Jinja2 version: 2.10
# Last messages:

# Loaded extensions:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.7.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/cmdline.py", line 303, in main
    args.warningiserror, args.tags, args.verbosity, args.jobs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.7.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 187, in __init__
    self.setup_extension(extension)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.7.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 411, in setup_extension
    self.registry.load_extension(self, extname)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.7.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/registry.py", line 315, in load_extension
    mod = __import__(extname, None, None, ['setup'])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.7.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/applehelp.py", line 20, in <module>
    from sphinx.builders.html import StandaloneHTMLBuilder
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.7.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/html.py", line 39, in <module>
    from sphinx.highlighting import PygmentsBridge
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.7.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/highlighting.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sphinx.ext import doctest
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.7.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/doctest.py", line 15, in <module>
    import doctest
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 355, in <module>
    class _OutputRedirectingPdb(pdb.Pdb):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Pdb'
```

Comment: Looking at [this sphinx bug](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/576) it seems it could be due to a name clash between the standard `pdb` module and a `pdb` module defined by another (custom?) library with higher precedence in `sys.path`. Can you try to run `python -c 'import pdb; print(pdb)'` and post the output ?

Comment: @etene output: <module 'pdb' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pdb.pyc'> and how can I find that higher precedence pdb?

Comment: This looks like it's going to be a bit difficult to investigate. I'm pretty sure there's a rogue `pdb` module that's being loaded in your path, but being unfamiliar with Homebrew it's going to be difficult for me to help you. If I were you though I'd try to set my pythonpath to `/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.7.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` and import `pdb` and `doctest` to see if that could give new clues.

Comment: @etene thanks I'll try

Comment: Did you install Xcode, like the warning suggests? `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Yes I have Xcode on my mac. I'm a iOS developer for most time now

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the Apple Command Line Tools

```
➜  ~ brew install python
Warning: Building python from source:
  The bottle needs the Apple Command Line Tools to be installed.
  You can install them, if desired, with:
    xcode-select --install
```

After running `xcode-select --install` and going through the installation, I coul successfully install Python using brew.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of find a way to work around this situation now. But unfortunately have no clue what is the real cause.

What I do is delete anything that seems relate to pdb in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. I don't need python debugger anyway. After that reinstall python by brew is ok